# Add button in fullcalendar v4 event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

In my fullcalendar v4.3.1 app I want to add some buttons with jsvascript function to events
example with decision I make it as :

```
window.calendarEventsObject = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ['dayGrid'],

    eventRender: function (eventInfo) {

        eventInfo.el.querySelector('.fc-title').append("<i class='fa fa-external-link pull-right'>7890</i>");
        // I see text in title , but not html element, as I expected  


        // eventInfo.el.querySelector('.fc-title').html("<i class='fa fa-external-link pull-right'>7890</i>");
        // If to uncomment  the lline above I got error eventInfo.el.querySelector(...).html is not a function
    },

    events: eventsList,

    showNonCurrentDates: false,

    editable: true,
    allDaySlot: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    selectOverlap: false,
    fixedWeekCount: false,

    aspectRatio: 0.4,
    height: 700,

});
```

Which way is valid ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ".html is not a function" error occurs because .html is a [jquery function](https://api.jquery.com/html/) and `el` is not a jQuery object (as of fullCalendar 4).

And `.append()` only appends plain text, not HTML. This is [mentioned in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)

If you want to append a HTML string then the simplest way is to use `innerHTML`:

```
eventRender: function (eventInfo) {
  eventInfo.el.querySelector('.fc-title').innerHTML += "<i class='fa fa-external-link pull-right'>7890</i>";
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/JjPJXeb