# Full calendar 4.0 fc-more(2+ more) popup over ride

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I need help related to disappearance of the [image: fc-more(2+ more)] popup in each day cell block, When there are too many events in a day, a link that looks like “+2 more” is displayed. How to avoid this popup, my requirement is default eventLimit: 2 and next for the remaining it should show a button, and click on this button, It should navigates to day mode similar as in the above screenshot.

Thanks & Regards, 
Prabha

Comment: Have you studied this part of the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-popover ? I think it gives you the information you need in order to complete your requirement. If you are still having a problem after reading that, then please show the code you tried and explain what your issue is. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, I read that, my requirement is I don't want to that default modal popup, I want to put a small button (with 3 dots) as mentioned in the attached image, than click on that button , then the monthview should change to dayview. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Ok well you can do all of that using the information I gave you . What didn't you understand from the documentation? There is a way for you to change the text of the link, and a way for you to change what happens when it is clicked. Read the specific articles for all of the options listed there.

Comment: How can completely avoid/hide the "+2 more" by disabling a particular param in during the init of FullCalendar object And if events length > 2, I want to add a small html button with a customized class, clicking on this button I want to call calendar.changeview('timeGridDay')  to navigate to that particular day view, currently I am in month mode.

Comment: I want to add a button with tooltip(click for more cells) instead of 'n+ more' default hyperlink, checking one of the link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57656685/add-button-in-fullcalendar-v4-event. please share your thoughts.

Comment: That link has nothing to do with what you're asking here

Comment: Yes, how can we achieve this.

Comment: Seriously I don't really understand how this is difficult. Declare https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimitText as a function to return "..." as the text for the link. Use CSS to make it look like a button instead of a link, if you want to

Comment: Then use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimitClick to change what happens when you click that link. If you notice, one of the options is "day".

Comment: Really, you replied only five minutes after I last commented, asking again. You clearly had not had time to read that documentation fully and actually try something. If you don't try, then you won't learn or succeed will you? Try it, if you still get stuck, show your code. Then we can talk again.

Comment: Hi, no. Recently I started full calendar concepts, going through the documentation, got it. Tried the day option other than of popup, thank you.

Comment: Hi ADyson, I added 2 options eventLimit: true, eventLimitClick: "day", now when I click on more link it navigates to day view, but a text '7890' appended for each every event title, and also as per the time scheduled, they did not set to that time, suppose one event is scheduled at 11:00 and other at 11:30, ..12:00, but the events are not fit for the exact time, working on this, thank you for the provided details.

Comment: Ok. I could potentially help you with that if you provide your code

Comment: Hi @ADyson, I achieved, the code is: eventLimitClick: function(cellInfo) {cal.gotoDate(cellInfo.date).changeview(day);}, then click on 'events more' link, redirected to day mode, another need is, I have 5 dropdowns& 5 htmlbuttons in page,select/click on any one OR ALL,the events in full calendar should be filtered, I tried as : eventRender: lert(info.event.extendedProps.cellName].indexOf($('#cellName_selector').val()));
        //return ['all', info.event.title].indexOf($('#cellName_selector').val()) >= 0 ||
        //['all', info.event.title].indexOf($('#cellName_selector1').val()) >= 0; ||

Comment: That's good. If you solved it all, you should add to the Answer section below though, rather than in comments. P.S. As per docs you should be able to shorten eventLimitClick option to `eventLimitClick: "day"` (assuming a day view is defined in your `header` option somewhere).

Comment: If you have another need regarding filtering, you should ask another question and show your code - it's not part of this issue. Then someone can answer it properly.

Comment: HI @ADyson, please have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62105331/fullcalendar-daygrid-from-and-to-ranges, I posted for another requirement, before posting this, I tried in my local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimitClick to change what happens when you click that link. If you notice, one of the options is "day". – ADyson 
Thanks a lot Adyson

Answer (score 0):

Using the below function in calendar intialisation we can remove the default more link text '+n more'.

```
eventLimitText: function() {
return " ";
}
```

And using the following CSS(in HTML style tag) we can insert a button like appearance instead of default text.

```
a.fc-more {background-size: contain;cursor: pointer;width: 14px;height: 6px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
background-image: url(dots.png);
background-color: #F0F0F0;
border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-radius: 4px;
margin-top: 10px;
float: right;
background-position: center;
}
```

dots.png is the image that has 3 horizontal dots.
Using the below function in calendar instantiation we can click on 'more button' to change to day view.

```
eventLimit: 3,
eventLimitClick: function(cellInfo) {
calendar.gotoDate(cellInfo.date);
calendar.changeView('timeGridDay');
}
```

Below image is my local calendar click more button view with hover text(click for more cells) and the hover css style as:

```
a.fc-more:hover:after {
 content: 'Click for more cells';
 font-size: 9px;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -2px;
 margin-left: 15px;
 line-height: 2em;
 width: 12em;
 border-radius: 0.3em;
 background: #ffffcc;
 display: inline-block;
 }
```

[image: My local click for more button If eventlimit > 2]

[image: dots.png]