# Fullcalendar dayGrid from and to ranges

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar

I am facing issue to set full calendar view for ranges of selected dates, As an example when I select dates from May 1 to May 7th using the code

```
calendar.changeView('dayGrid', {start: startDate,end: endDate});
```

it shows all the selected dates in vertical columns as in the first section of the figure.

Similarly when I select dates from May 1 to May 8th it shows all the 8 columns in vertical view as in the second section of the figure.

In another case, suppose if I select dates multiples of 7, such as from May 1 to May 14, the calendar view shows 2 horizontal rows, one for each 7 days attached in last section of the figure.

So I tried to get the same horizontal view for 10 days like 7 dates are in first horizontal row and the remaining 3 days in second horizontal row, but could not able to get it. Please suggest the steps to achieve it.

[image]